# jetpack to edit inline theme CSS -- on topic?

Tags: discussion, support

Is it on topic to ask about using jetpack to edit inline CSS for a theme?  While I see similar questions, it seems to be regarded as off-topic.

The question I want to ask on the WP Devel. site is:

> how do I use, or where is the fine manual explaining how to use,
>   jetpack to edit css for a theme?  I can see in the dashboard that
>   jetpack offers this functionality, but there are so many css portions,
>   and it's not exactly clear, from firebug, which css entry relates to a
>   specific section of html.
>
> I can edit raw html, but the "clickey" nature of wordpress doesn't
>   make it entirely clear what's being modified (at least for me), or even **how** to actually edit the css (assuming I even found the correct css).

Comment: Could you elaborate on want you want to ask in full here? I get the keywords (jetpack, edit, inline(?) css) but it doesn't quite make sense to me what your question is in full.

Comment: @Rarst S/He wants a how to on using Jetpacks Inline CSS editor as the GUI seems to not make clear _"what changes what"_.

Answer (score 2):

How to use a plugins GUI is out of scope [as per the help centers "on topic" section](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

> Note that we **do not** handle questions:
>
> (...)
>
> **questions concerning third party plugins and themes.** As these required detailed knowledge of the workings of those plugins and themes, support is difficult and with thousands of plugins and themes available such knowledge is very specialized. Please consult the appropriate support forum for the plugin or theme in question.

The GUI of a plugin can change frequently (quicker than core does). There are more plugins out there than we have users, so it's impossible to offer support for each and every plugin. We would have to read into the plugins core, add a setup that can reproduce your issue, learn how the plugins works, etc. which is highly unlikely that someone is willing to do. Also it would only help a very limited group of people for a very limited amount of time (until the next change in the plugin). And than there is the fact that we would force another support route to watch on the plugins author.

**TL;TR** This question would be off topic.